# Run FileZilla on Debian

Tags: debian, packages, filezilla

I'm new on Debian and Linux, I installed FileZilla but I don't know how to run it.
whene I execute :

```
dpkg -l | grep -i "filezilla"
```

I get

```
ii  filezilla-common                     3.7.3-1                            all          Architecture independent files for filezilla
```

So I guess it installed.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is installed. Depending on the desktop environment or window manager you are using, you should find an entry for filezilla in the applications menu.

Otherwise, you can quickly launch it by opening a terminal window and issue the following command:

```
filezilla &
```

at the command prompt.

The & at the end of the command detaches filezilla from the terminal, so you can safely close your terminal window after launching the application.